# How can I automatically file an input box and click a search button?

Tags: javascript

I tried to fill a search input field with some text and hit the search button with this code:

```
document.getElementsByName('search')[0].value = '1234978';
document.getElementsByClassName('js_search_button')[0].click();
```

I see my text in the box and the button gets hit. But the data from the input box, was not submited.

Maybe the website has a protection, so that only keytrokes are accepted.

To crosscheck this I tried this code:

```
var iButton = document.getElementsByClassName('js_search_button')[0];
iButton.addEventListener('click', simulateInput);


function simulateInput() {
  var inp = document.getElementsByName("search")[0];
  var ev = new Event('input');
  
  inp.value =inp.value + '1234978';
  inp.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Here I get the right result if I manualy click the searchbutton with automaticly filled in the number.

I it possible to automate the click in this scenario, too ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, because of code sample I posted it as answer.

Are you selecting the right element for clicking? As you can see I click the buttons programmatically.

```js
function clicked(val) {
  console.log('button clicked:', val)
}

document.querySelectorAll(".txt")[0].value = 5;
document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[1].click()
document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[2].click()
document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[0].click()

document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[3].click()
```

```html
<input class='txt' type='text' />
<button class="btn" onclick="clicked(1)">a</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="clicked(2)">b</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="clicked(3)">c</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="clicked(4)">d</button>
```